# Враг перестает преследовать персонажа после столкновения

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я не понимаю, почему Move Towards перестает работать в Update. У врага есть 2 коллайдера, один на спрайте для получения урона, второй спереди для запуска атаки. И враг может атаковать издалека, то есть, если началась анимация атаки, то персонаж обязательно получит урон. Вражеская атака привязана к кадру анимации

Вот мой код

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health;
    public float speed;
    private Animator anim;
    private float timeBtwAttack;
    public float startTimeBtwAttack;
    private Player player;
    public int damage;
    private bool isAttacking = false;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<Player>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (speed == 0) 
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", false);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("isRunning", true);
        }

        if (health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject); 
        }

        if (player.transform.position.x > transform.position.x)
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        else
            transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 180, 0);

        transform.position = Vector2.MoveTowards(transform.position, player.transform.position, speed * Time.deltaTime);

        
        timeBtwAttack -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
        {
            if (timeBtwAttack <= 0 && !isAttacking)
            {
                isAttacking = true;
                anim.SetBool("attack", true);
            }
        }
    }

    public void EnemyAttack()
    {
        player.ChangeHealth(-damage);
        timeBtwAttack = startTimeBtwAttack;

        isAttacking = false;
        anim.SetBool("attack", false);
    }

    public void FinishAttack()
    {
        //isAttacking = false;
        //anim.SetBool("attack", false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Итак. Я не увидел проблем в коде, но у меня есть подозрения по поводу того, в чëм проблема.
Второй коллайдер. Это ужасная практика.

https://youtu.be/bXAsrI985_M

По этому видео можно сделать нормальную атаку, без второго коллайдера на один объект

Помимо этого, советую изучить SOLID(на будущее, не связано с проблемой). Это поможет сделать код "чистым"